# REGEXP_SUBSTR Hex range in Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, regex, utf-8, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am trying to check for certain invalid non-UTF8 characters. From one of the post in this forum, I found this query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This will be my first time visiting Seattle. ',
       UNISTR('[\FFFF-\DBFF\DFFF]')) as str FROM dual;
```

Which gives the following output:

```
str
-------------------------------------------
```

But the thing here is when I run the above query on Oracle 12c version, it works totally fine, but when I run the same on Oracle 11g(11.2.0.4) version, I get the following error:

```
ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression
12728. 00000 -  "invalid range in regular expression"
*Cause:    An invalid range was found in the regular expression.
*Action:   Ensure a valid range is being used.
```

Kindly provide your suggestions as to what is wrong that I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your range `[X-Y]` in the pattern is wrong, since:
X=`\FFFF` is greater than Y=`\DBFF` (I don't know what `\DBFF\DFFF` is supossed to do).
By analogy - this regular expression `[a-b]` is right because a < b:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'some text', '[a-b]')
```

but this regular expression `[b-a]` is wrong because b > a:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'some text', '[b-a]')
```

and you will get the same error in this case:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This will be my first time visiting Seattle.','[b-a]' ) FROM dual;
ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression
```

**----------
EDIT
----------**

> But then why the query executes fine in 12c and gives an error in 11g?

I am trying on Oracle 12.1.0.2.0, and get the same error

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This will be my first time visiting Seattle. ',
       UNISTR('[\FFFF-\DBFF\DFFF]')) as str FROM dual;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                                                  0
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                   0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0


Error starting at line : 3 in command -
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This will be my first time visiting Seattle. ',
       UNISTR('[\FFFF-\DBFF\DFFF]')) as str FROM dual
Error report -
ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression
```

Comment: But then why the query executes fine in 12c and gives an error in 11g?

Comment: @arsm4 I am trying on Oracle 12.1.0.2.0, and get the same error, please see a test case in my answer

Comment: can you please provide the output of this query `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');` Mine is `AL32UTF8` and `AL16UTF16`. Hence, the reason the above query works for me. Also, when you reverse, the sequence as per your suggestion do you get any output?

Comment: @arsm4 - AL32UTF8  AL16UTF16. If I reverse parameters, then the query works, but returns NULL.

Comment: I am really not sure, what's wrong here, but believe me that when I run the above query in my Oracle 12c(12.1.0.2.0), I do get an output as smiley.